# Using the output of 'fdisk -l | grep Disk' to put in an 'if' statement

Tags: bash, shell, awk

My goal is to use the finding from 'fdisk -l | grep Disk' to run an if statement based off what it finds. Basically, my school has 2 harddrive sizes, 320GB and 500GB. If it finds a 320GB drive, it should continue with the partition. If it finds a 500GB it should stop.

```
$ fdisk -l | grep Disk
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00027998
```

I want to "grab" that 320. Can that be done using awk or maybe a head/tail -c? I'm extremely new to shell script. Thanks!

Comment: Consider consulting `/proc/partitions` instead, or maybe `/sys/block/<device>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
size=$(fdisk -l | awk '$1=="Disk" && $2 ~ /^\/dev\/.*/ {print $3}')
if (( ${size%.*} == 320 )); then ...
```